# Ember programmatically call controller action from hbs template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a defined action on my controller that makes a modal visible. In my 
hbs template, I am able to create a button and assign it the action. When I do this, I can make the modal appear by clicking the button.

I am trying to show the modal (call the controller action) without having to click anything. Is this possible? I want the modal to pop up based on a conditional on the model automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a pretty straightforward way to do this, 
just create a computed alias of the model property that you want

```
// controller
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  showModal: Ember.computed.alias('model.showModal')
});

// template
{{#if showModal}}
  <p>Showing modal</p>
{{/if}}
```

that's it

working example: https://ember-twiddle.com/3e86c841e9d7ea54d4febd74b5463fb8?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

Answer (score 0):

You could create a component, add the button to the component and then pass the model and action into the component.

Then in the component's `init` lifecycle hook, do your model conditional check and call the passed in action if it's `true`.

```
// some-template.hbs
{{component-with-button
    model=model
    openModal=(action 'openModal')
}}

// components/component-with-button.js
Component.extend({
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        if (this.get('model.conditionalCheck')) {
            this.get('openModal')();
        }
    }
});
```

From my knowledge, there's no lifecycle hook in a controller which fires every time you visit a specific page. Adding your check to a component guarantees your check will fire each time you visit the page as it will always render the button component.